# Glowy-Is it a new word?

Tags: is-it-a-word

> And the glow of a campfire was not, well, as **glowy** without the darkness of night.

[its context](https://www.questia.com/newspaper/1P2-32616383/grateful-for-the-dark-that-brackets-the-day)

I didn't get "glowy" in the dictionary. I'm guessing it's a made up word. Do you think it is acceptable？

Comment: All words are made up. But anyway, adding a *y* to a noun to form an adjective not in the dictionary has been a thing for quite a while, following the pattern of more established *noun+y* adjectives that are in the dictionary.

Comment: 'The dictionary' being? It's in one or two of the readily available online dictionaries. This hints strongly that it's a neologism.

Comment: Why are you looking for it in a dictionary anyway. I do not understand. The meaning is perfectly clear without a dictionary. As to how new the word is, COCA has cites for it going back to 1990. So at least one full generation of speakers.

Comment: @Edwin Cambridge Online, webster app

Comment: @Reg Actually, I was told this word is not on the dictionary. I was curious about how you think of the phenomenon--the meaning is clear but not in a dictionary. If it is not so acceptable, I think I should avoid using it In a more formal discourse.

Comment: 'Glowy' **_is_** listed in Lexico, but caveated as 'informal'. 'In the dictionary' is a phrase best binned. OED contains over ten times as many words as some dictionaries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's a word. Depending on your definition of "new," it could be centuries old or (in current usage) at least 35 years old.

**Glowy** is a formation made from a noun (**glow**) and a generative suffix (**-y**, described in [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/-y?utm_campaign=sd&utm_medium=serp&utm_source=jsonld) as "characterized by" and other meanings). The suffix can be used to create nonce words (words created for singular occasions) that, irrespective of their aesthetic qualities, would be understood by speakers. Here, I'll play around with some nouns I've just used to invent words:

> That word ending is **suffixy**.
>
> A gerund feels **nouny**.
>
> This is getting **nonce-wordy**.

Because someone can take an existing word, add a generative prefix, and trust that many speakers will recognize it, **glowy** (*characterized by glow*) is a word.

---

Is it an acceptable word? It certainly appears in print. It's a word that has been used periodically since at least the 1980s, as I found in [COHA](https://www.english-corpora.org/coha/). This is from novelist Alice Walker in *The Color Purple* from 1982:

> They black and smooth and kind of **glowy** from the lamplight.

Then here's another from Malcolm Gladwell in *Blink* (2005):

> They haven't been married that long. They're still in the **glowy** phase.

This usage has begun to appear in dictionaries. Here's [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/glowy):

> (informal) Giving off a steady light.
>
> ‘soft, glowy bulbs’

Note that this definition is pretty general. It doesn't describe the figurative usage Gladwell seems to employ - does a new marriage literally give off a steady light? No - this must come from figurative senses of glow, like ": warmth of feeling or emotion" ([Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/glow)). **Glowy** retains the figurative uses of its root noun as well as the literal one.

Also note that the word does feel informal. I might avoid *glowy* in an academic essay, but *glowy* would be in my word hoard for creative writing and writing for a general audience.

---

Finally, it's a word that has existed before. The [Oxford English Dictionary](https://oed.com/view/Entry/79230) marks an obsolete use with a very similar meaning:

> Glowing; bright.
>
> 1670   S. Wilson Lassels's Voy. Italy (new ed.) i. 154   This fire..appeared to mee..to be..of the same **glowy** colour.

[Early English Books Online](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/e/eebogroup/) turns up 9 results, showing it's not merely a nonce usage. So it is an *old word* that has recently been reinvented.

Answer (score 0):

*Glowy* is defined by [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/glowy) as:

> Giving off a steady light.